# SoftLayer OS Reload API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have the same issue as [SL ReloadOS API inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080814/sl-reloados-api-inquiry) and I am using maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.softlayer.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>softlayer-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
Server.Service serverService =  Server.service(client, hardware.getId()); fails to compile with error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Hardware.Service to Server.Service
serverService.reloadOperatingSystem("FORCE", config);
```

Since I am using maven,
how to change the code of `com.softlayer.api.service.hardware.Server` class?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed and it was released on **master branch** of [SoftLayer API Client for Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java).

Issue: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/21

Follow these steps to use master branch:

1. Download the **softlayer-java-master.zip**(91kb)
   Using git:

   > git clone -b master https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java.git
2. Open a command prompt (I suppose that you are using Windows), go to 
   path that you unzipped the project and compile the project using
   maven **mvn compile**
3. Open the project and try to run the script that you have

Comment: Well, there shouldn't exist any dependency trouble. After you compiled the project (Make sure that the project was built successfully), you should import this to Eclipse

Comment: Thanks it works. I just converted it into eclipse project and imported the project.